# BLE Samsung : problems writing to characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have some simple code that runs fine on Android 4.3 (non samsung). When translating to Samsung's BLE SDK for < 4.3, I find that I can read and be notified but I can't write to my characteristic

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(device_, UUID_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(UUID_CHARACTERISTIC);
characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{0x01});
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Any idea what's wrong ? I don't get any error/exception. onCharacteristicWrite is not called either, and when checking with the 4.3 device I see the characteristic hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was wrong : I had to space read and writes more (200 ms seemed to work)

Comment: Hi ! On some Samsung device with different android version I have the same problem. Do you Have  found a solution?

Comment: another thing that helped : issue the reads/writes on the uithread (seems strange but worked)

Comment: I already do writes on ui thread but Samsung continue to gives me some problems :/